# CSS for all browsers, word should not be break, href link should be break, hypen text should not be break

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

Looking for a CSS property which will run on all the browsers where condition for word is as follows.
1. word should not be break.
2. href link text should be break within the html tag.
3. hyphen text should not be break.
4. The content may be in DIV, span or in a tag having multi lines.

Comment: Can't you just have two rules, one which specifies all elements' text can't break, and the other which specifically targets anchor tags and allows them to break?

Answer (score 5):

CSS has white-space property which can be used.
URL : https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

For all links, you can add the following code:
a{white-space:initial;}

Comment: Thanks a lot :) This seems to be helpful, but for text like the href link is not broken,